# Whitespace removing in file

Tags: python, whitespace

I want to remove all whitespaces in my file using python. For that, I am using:

```
output = "file.out"

with open(output) as templist:
    templ = templist.read().splitlines()

filelist = []
for line in templ:
    if line.startswith("something"):
        filelist.append(line.strip(' '))
```

I managed to append the required lines, but the whitespace removing do not work. Can anybody help me? =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.strip()` only removes whitespace from the start and end of a string.

I think the easiest way to go about this would be to use a regex:

```
import re
...
for line in templ:
    if line.startswith("something"):
        filelist.append(re.sub(r"\s+", "", line))
```

`\s` matches any kind of whitespace (spaces, newlines, tabs etc.).